# Law of conservation of momentum is wrong(Part 1)

Tags: momentum

My question is here as I thought of a situation where law of conservation of momentum is proved wrong.
Suppose in vacuum a body made up of matter of mass 1kg and speed 10m/s collides with antimatter of same mass and moving in same direction but at velocity of 8m/s.
Total momentum is 18 before collision.
After collision mass will be 0
Total momentum is now 0
Law of conservation of momentum fails.
Please tell me whether I  am mistaken somewhere.

If you say that gamma rays took up the task to transfer momentum in form of energy then I want to say that from the time of collision to the time of transfer of momentum the momentum with value 18 would be not present in the universe and 5his law also states that total momentum in universe always remain same.
Either the law is fully wrong or partially or I am mistaken somewhere. Please comment on this.

Comment: Why did you delete this only to post the exact same question?

Answer (score 2):

The products of the annihilation reaction carry off the momentum. Note that electromagnetic radiation carries momentum as given by the Poynting vector. What is wrong is not momentum conservation but the assumption that momentum must involve mass.

Answer (score 1):

> Total momentum is 18 before collision. After collision mass will be 0

You're thinking that matter + antimatter = nothing.

That is not correct.

matter + antimatter = a whole crapload of stuff (like photons)

Take a wild guess what the total momentum of that (whole crapload) is?

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly analyzed this type of collision you need to use $4$-momentum conservation, which has been extensively verified as correct by experiment.  In a simple version of your example the momentum would be carried by the (massless) photons created by the pair-annihilation process.  This process would still conserve $4$-momentum: the time component of this vector is related to the energy and the space components to the momentum $\vec k$ of the photons.

Answer (score 1):

Your first error starts here:

> Suppose in vacuum a body made up of matter of mass 1kg and speed 10m/s collides with antimatter of same mass and moving in same direction but at velocity of 8m/s

Once you invoke antimatter, you are invoking quantum mechanics and [special relativity.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/relcon.html) Each of your bodies is described by a four momentum, whose four-length is the mass, as far as mainstream physics goes.

Your second error lies into thinking when matter meets antimatter four vectors stop existing. Momentum conservation always holds , and four vector of before the interaction is the same as the one after the interaction.

Therefore the third error lies into thinking that matter and antimatter interact and go to 0 mass. That is forbidden, the mass will be the initial mass of the two four vectors interacting, the output can be a plethora of particles, among which there will be photons, but all the four vectors of the interaction obey energy and momentum conservation.

> If you say that gamma rays took up the task to transfer momentum in form of energy then I want to say that from the time of collision to the time of transfer of momentum the momentum with value 18 would be not present in the universe

Mainstream physics has a way of calculating the probability of getting the end particles, BUT ALWAYS IN THE MATHEMATICS ENERGY AND MOMENTUM ARE CONSERVED. There is no "in between" and the mathematical models  fit the data beautifully

> and this law also states that total momentum in universe always remain same. Either the law is fully wrong or partially or I am mistaken somewhere.

Lets not put the universe in the picture, because we would have to use General Relativity and you are not yet familiar with [special relativity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/relcon.html).

In general momentum and energy are always conserved, period, and this is continually validated by our experiments and observations.

Answer (score -3):

The conservation laws are not wrong - to every force there is an opposite and equal reaction force. Force is related to momentum as

$F = \frac{dp}{dt}$

Inertial effects tend to zero in space, so it easier to push a thing in space say, than it is here on Earth, but the momentum is always equivalent to the force you apply. Antimatter on the other hand, meeting normal matter, is a special decay process, in which the energy released is equivalent to the rest energy or relativistic energy, depending on the motion of the particles, you cannot get more or less energy than which the system already has.

The decay of an electron and positron for instance, will release the energy accordingly as understood through the energy-mass equivalence and force is related to energy as

$Fvt = E$

And momentum is related to energy as

$pv = E$

But again, be careful how you define the motion of the system, because under relativistically moving particles, they carry more momentum than one at rest - so if a relativistically moving particle hits an electron at rest, radiation is released accordingly such that conservation is preserved.

The relativistic formula of the energy-mass is

$E = \sqrt{p^2c^2 + m^2c^4}$

Comment: When an electron and a positron interact, disappear, and create photons, this is called “annihilation”, not “decay”.

Comment: It is actually a special decay process.

Comment: annihilation is just a fancy word, but in textbooks and learned physics books, we know it is a special decay process.

Comment: No physics book that I have read calls this a decay. No professor of mine ever called it a decay. You can use whatever language you want, but that won’t make it mainstream.

Comment: The your professors are not quite prophetic nor is your textbooks quite analytical :)

Comment: Electrons and positrons are stable particles, they cannot decay. However, when an electron & positron meet they form an unstable system called [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium), and then shortly afterwards either the electron & positron scatter, going their separate ways, or the electron & positron annihilate, so the positronium decays into photons (usually). See the link for details on the halflife of positronium, and its decay modes. So even though we say that positronium decays, we never say that the electron or positron decay.

Comment: They certainly do decay, what part of antimatter-matter reaction decaying into photons, is not being understood? As I said, it is a special decay process, a very well-known one in fact among the physics community.

Comment: ''searchers have observed spontaneous transformations between particles and their antiparticles, occurring millions of times per second before they decay.'' - https://home.cern/science/physics/matter-antimatter-asymmetry-problem

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=po0eXaygIsycsAegsbDYCw&q=antimatter+and+matter+decay+process&oq=antimatter+and+matter+decay+process&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160.774.13672..13888...9.0..0.367.5521.21j20j3j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..35i39j0i131j0j0i10j0i22i30j0i22i10i30j33i21j33i22i29i30.wmUxUhFlikg

Comment: https://cosmosmagazine.com/physics/cern-study-sheds-light-on-matter-antimatter-mystery

Comment: https://www.sciencealert.com/this-unseen-form-of-radioactive-decay-could-help-explain-where-all-the-antimatter-is

Comment: Certainly, electrons alone cannot decay, what you are forgetting is they cannot decay into anything smaller alone. But when meeting an antiparticle, it is well-known to be a special decay process in which they reduce back to gamma radiation. So an apology would be nice?